# If session expires, automatically redirect home - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Is there somewhere in codeigniter where I could configure an automatic redirect to my root page if the user's session is expired (I am not trying to extend the session expiration's time)?

> Situational example:
>
> User logs in, leaves page idle for one day, returns to page that
>   requires validated session and sees PHP errors everywhere.

I'd prefer for anything in this situation to be redirected to my root login page.

Thank you!

Comment: The example you describe should never happen. Can you post the code that checks for a valid session?

Comment: There is no configuration for automatic redirection to root page in CI. We can achieve by writing the redirection code in common controller. I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this content into your constructor function because when the controller run constructor will execute first.

```
 function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
         if(empty($this->session->userdata("login_session_user")))
         {
         redirect(site_url(),'refresh');
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below code in each function and place your function code inside the if loop. This will be use full for you. Thank you .

```
$this->load->helper('url');
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))

    {  
         // You function code should be placed here .

    }
    else{

        redirect(site_url(),'refresh');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    $session = session();
    $this->Login_model = new Login_model();
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $request = \Config\Services::request();

    if ($session->has('user_id')) {
        return redirect()->to('Home');
    }
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).