# Login and Logout history using codeigniter and php admin side

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am suppose to create a login and logout history for my admin. My problem is I can't create a complete idea about it. My login is in session with the help of Code Igniter. Any idea/help guys?

Comment: do you want to save to db everytime user logs in and out?

Comment: Yes sir :) Do you have any idea/experience about this? Or any references?

Comment: i already added 2 new columns in my users table, date_Login and date_Logout with DATETIME type.

Comment: on login just update login date and time and same on logout but if u need complete history of a user login and logout then create new table that will save ,multiple id details for login and logout

Comment: I already have it. My main concern is how to get the Date and Time of Login and Logout in a Session.

Comment: Save Sessions to DB, logout table with id to session id and then when user does actions on the site, have a core controller update the logout date/time?

Answer (score 0):

do you really need to save the session to db? since you have not posted details of you table where you will be saving the user login/out history 
my answer will be limited to assumptions.
for login and logout history i will assume you have a fully functioning
login and logout function already in place, so I will be enlisting the posible steps you may go

- you can have a separate table for saving the login history of each user, so a user_id may have 
  one-to-many login history
- logging in requires a user action, so evertime a user has successful login, you will save to db the user_id and datetime
- `'user_id' => $user_id, 'date_login' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") // get current timestamp`
- for logging out with user action (user clicks the logout button) you may do same thing like the login process,
  once the user clicks the logout button, save/update the logout detail of the user: `'user_id' => $user_id, 'date_logout' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

if the session has expired and you want to logout the user and save the logout time in your login history table

- for expired session, you could put a function in the constructor of your controller/s that checks/validates the 
  session of the user if it is expired or not, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623714/if-session-expires-automatically-redirect-home-codeigniter)
- once you validated that the session has expired, save/update the logout detail of the user and then logout the user: `'user_id' => $user_id, 'date_logout' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`